# System is taking more than 100GB of space on my macbook

Tags: mac, macos

I realized that the Mac OSX Sierra is taking more than 100GB+ on my machine. I don't think this is normal. I clicked on manage and I didn't see any very large system file.

I wonder how can I reduce the disk footprint of the system?

I have already optimized my document and personal storage, but I don't understand why the OS would take 100GB

[image]

Something is seriously wrong.... since the time I made this post. Now the OS has grown and taken up my entire disk.

[image]

Comment: Have you done anything with Boot Camp? Partitioning?

Comment: Also, have you tried looking at/clearing any cache folders? I find that a lot of data hides in there.

Comment: No  I haven't done bootcamp. I used a utility called "cleanmymac" and it cleared all caches and that freed 9GB of space. but the OS is still taking more than 100GB+

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch What is the size of your '~/Music' folder? Currently my system is showing 5.0GB for 'iTunes' (red section) and 130GB for 'System' (yellow section). My 'Music' folder is 111GB so I've deduced that for some reason it's incorrectly lumping the contents of my Music folder in with 'System'. Could this possibly be the same situation for you?

Comment: No its not. in my case the "system" has eaten up all the space. this is not the same as other question

Comment: Nevertheless the tools metioned in the answer to the other question will help you to identify what exactly is eating up all the space.